# How to query most recent 3 months row from a table using postgresql and kenx.js

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I am using Postgresql db and Knenx running on a Node server and trying to write a function that queries the table `customeractivity` (shown in pic below). My goal is to retrieve the recent 3 months row where it matches the `customernbr`. I have written the function `getRecentTransaction` as mentioned below:

```
getRecentTransaction = async (customerId, db) => {
   return await db('customeractivity')
      .select('docdesc', 'origdocamt', 'docdate',)
      .whereRaw(`docdate < INTERVAL '? month'`, [1])
      .andWhere('customernbr', '=', `${customerId}`)
      .then(recentTransaction => recentTransaction[0])
      .catch(error => Promise.reject(error));
}
```

As you all can see i am able to use PSequel to retrieve the proper data. However, I am struggling to write the same query with Knex.

[image: PSequel]

Answer (score 0):

The SQL you provided is:

```
SELECT * FROM customeractivity
  WHERE docdate > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '3 months'
    AND customernbr = '713610'
  ORDER BY docdate DESC;
```

The Knex version of this query is:

```
knex('customeractivity')
  .where('docdate', '>', knex.raw(`CURRENT_DATE - '3 MONTH'::INTERVAL`))
  .andWhere('customernbr', '713610');
```

Note that `return await` is redundant (and won't do what you probably expect). All you really need to do is return the Knex chain:

```
const getRecentTransaction = (customerId, db) =>
  db('customeractivity')
    .where('docdate', '>', knex.raw(`CURRENT_DATE - '3 MONTH'::INTERVAL`))
    .andWhere('customernbr', customerId);
```

and await it in the calling code:

```
const result = await getRecentTransaction(5, db);
```